# wordpress image uploader

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Как передать `url` в переменную `instance`?

```
<?php

class Porcnakan_widget_nkari extends WP_Widget {


  public function __construct() {
    $args = array(
      'name' => 'Porcnakan',
      'description' => 'fuuuuuuuu',
      'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
    );

    parent::__construct('boomteme-widhj', '', $args);

  }


  public function form($instance) {

    ?>

    <div class="media-widget-control" id="my_custom_metabox">
      <p>
        <label for="">Title: </label>
        <input name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"
               value="<?php echo $title; ?>" type="text" class="widefat"/>
      </p>

      <div method="post" class="media-widget-preview">

        <div class="attachment-media-view">
          <img name="aaaa" id='mher'/>
          <div id="image-tag" class="placeholder">No image selected</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="media-widget-buttons">
        <input type="button" id="img-remove-field" class="custom_image_data button hidden" value="Remove Image"/>
        <input type="button" id="image-upload-button" onclick="Myown()" class="button" value="Add Image"/>
        <input type="button" id="image-delete-button" class="button hidden" value="Delate Image"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('img_textarea'); ?>"
                  id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('img_textarea'); ?>" type="text"
                  class="widefat"><?php echo $img_textarea; ?></textarea>
      </p>
    </div>

    <script>


      var customUploader = wp.media({
        title: 'Select an Image',
        button: {
          text: 'Use this image'
        },
        multiple: false
      });

      function Myown() {
        customUploader.open();
      };
      customUploader.on('select', function () {
        var attachment = customUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        alert(attachment.url);
      });

    </script>

    <?php
  }

  public function widget($args, $instance) {
    var_dump($instance);


    ?>


    <?php
  }


}

function register_porcnakan_widget() {
  register_widget('Porcnakan_widget_nkari');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'register_porcnakan_widget');
?>
```

Comment: Чтобы что-то передать из js в php, создана технология ajax. Основы ajax в WordPress изложены здесь: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html